# android listview

Tags: android, listview

here I want to display list row with text and button . I want to give listener to button only .

Comment: ok, do you have a specific problem? if so, please elaborate.

Comment: then why dont you start coding ? I think you somebody gave you wrong some information. You **dont** get source codes on this site. You have to write it by yourself.

Comment: @Reno: Even if you're perfectly correct in your comment, I don't see the point in being so harsh (with all due respect).

Comment: Start learning `How to Code` first!. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **android:clickable="false"** to listview and use following for button in your adapter.

```
button.setClickable(true);
button.setFocusable(true);
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```